# Scrapy skip one method

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping local page_source files. The Scrapy completely skipped the `parse_nextfile()` function. It works perfectly for the `parse()` function. I do not know why it happens?

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from linkedin.items import LinkedinItem
import glob, os

class ProfilesSpider(Spider):

    name = 'profiles'
    allowed_domains = ["file://127.0.0.1"]
    start_urls = ["file://127.0.0.1/path/to/file/text.txt"]

    def parse_nextfile(self,response):

       #retrieve local files directory
       request(url, callback = self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
       #scraping the page_source file
```

Comment: I don't see any reason `parse_nextfile` will get called, `parse` is the default callback of scrapy requests, if you want `parse_nextfile` to be called, you will have to specify in the request `callback=self.parse_nextfile`

Comment: Thanks @bluesummers, It works perfectly.

Comment: I'll put it as an answer, please vote it up and mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parse` is the default callback of any Scrapy request.

If you need another method to parse a request you will need to specify in the request `callback=self.parse_nextfile`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I should know the basic of scrapy better.